# Accessing 2d Array php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello all i keep having error everytime i access the array "Undefined index: total";
I did manage to get the data out of the array but i wish the notice of undefined index will go away.
Below is my implementation.
Define the array :

```
$districttemp = array(
    'areaname'=>array(),
    'total'=>array()
);
```

Accessing the array:

```
foreach($districttemp as $key => $obj){
         echo $key;
         echo "&nbsp";
         echo $obj['areaname'];
         echo "&nbsp";
         echo $obj['total'];
         echo "<br>";
}
```

It is when i accessing the array that occur the error.

Comment: foreach loops through your array ($districttemp ) like $obj = array(), Since the inner array doesn't have a field named 'total' , it will through errors.

Comment: What, no comment, no thank you, not even a "that does not help"??? Its rude to eat and run you know

Answer (score 0):

You are processing the array incorrectly. The foreach is delivering you ONE item from the array at a time and therefore you should output a single item. Also each member of your array is also an array so you will need to also loop around each of those items one at a time.

```
foreach($districttemp as $key => $obj){
   echo $key;
   echo "&nbsp";
   if ( is_array($obj) ) {
        foreach ( $obj as $key1 => $obj1 ) {
            echo $key1;
            echo "&nbsp";
            echo $obj1;
        }
   } else {
        echo $obj;
        echo "&nbsp";
   }
} 
echo "<br>";
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

`$key` is "areaname" or "total" in your loop. `$obj` in your case is an empty array because you are looping `$districttemp`. `$obj`contains `$districttemp['total']`and `$districttemp['arename']` in the iterations.